# How to correctly implement OpenSessionInView with Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 3 (in liferay portlets)?

Tags: hibernate, spring, lazy-loading, portlet

I have some problems in implementing the OpenSessionInView pattern. 
From various resources on the web i configured my application in this way: 
1) in my dispatcher-servlet.xml I have an interceptor that should get all my requests with a spring class OpenSessionInViewInterceptor:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
         <list>
              <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor"/>
         </list>
       </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactoryAnnotation"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

2) then I have configured transactions in my Service layer with AOP in this way:

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* it.jdk.crm.service..*Service.*(..))" id="gestioneComunicazioniOperation"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="gestioneComunicazioniOperation"/>
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="txManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactoryAnnotation" />
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="txManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactoryAnnotation" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Is it possible that the two configurations are in conflict? 
I have a requirement that my Service layer (used in portlets) should be transaction-bounded, is it in conflict with the OpenSessionInView? If it is, then how can I prevent `LazyInitializationException` errors in my controllers?

EDIT: 
the exception is occurring in the view, when i call

`<c:forEach items="${communication.questions}" var="question" >`

with exception

`ERROR [jsp:165] org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.*.Communication.questions, no session or session was closed`

and the code in the controller that calls the view is like:

```
@RequestMapping(params="action=dettagli")
    public ModelAndView dettagliComunicazione(@ModelAttribute("communication") Communication c) {
        Communication communication = null;
        try {
            communication = communicationService.findById(c.getId());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        Hashtable l = new Hashtable();
        l.put("communication", communication);
        return new ModelAndView("communication/details", l);

    }
```

that gets resolved in a file by the bean in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Comment: Is the exception occurring in the controller, or in the view? Either way, can we see the source for the controller, and any view resolvers you have configured in the context?

Comment: Maybe I should add the interceptor to the `viewResolver` instead to the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`?